# MongoDB scripts and CSV files: can I use require.js to load jquery.csv?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, csv, requirejs

I am writing scripts that need to load a CSV file, do some processing on it and then save it into a MongoDB. What is the best way to load the CSV file?

Right now my stub code looks like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var $ = jQuery = require("jquery");
require("./jquery.csv.js");

var sample = "../data/ucl-ramsay-20131014.csv";
fs.readFile(sample, "UTF-8", function(err, csv) {
  $.csv.toArrays(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
      print(data[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

However this fails because it seems MongoDB doesn't come with `require` by default. Should I load the CSV file another way, or should I be loading require.js first?

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to use node.js modules in a mongodb shell?  The code you specified is copied right from the node-usage.js file from the jquery-csv web site.  So what does this have to do with mongodb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't easily do all that scripting within the MongoDB console, and I'd not recommend you try. Instead, I'd suggest you install a copy of NodeJS for your platform, then using whatever csv parser you'd like, you can easily loop through the rows and insert documents into a MongoDB database.

In a file `csv_import.js` add code like this (add your code to parse the CSV file):

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var async = require('async');

  var csv = []; // build the csv into an array...
  // putting the data into the 'test' database:
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('csv_import');
    async.every(csv, function(row, callback) {
       // build the csv row into an object literal
       var data = { "name" : .... }; // make this fit your data correctly
       collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) {
          // signal that this row is done inserting
          // by calling the callback passed with every row
          callback(err);
       });
    }, function() {
        // all rows have been inserted, so close the db connection
        db.close();
    });
  })
```

Then, just

```
node csv_import.js
```

Comment: This suggestion helped a lot. Ultimately it is a simple script and I ended up writing it using `MongoClient` and `node-csv`. Rather than `async` I just used `jQuery` promises - if I could force MongoClient and node-csv method calls to be synchronous my code would be a lot prettier and a lot simpler, but it works.